# Windows terminal - Script opening panes and SSHing to servers

Tags: ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, windows-terminal

I'm currently using Windows Terminal to front WSL 2 Ubuntu. I use it to SSH out to multiple servers. I'm now at a point where I'd need to run similar \ identical tasks across multiple servers, so I'd like to be able to say *Open a new pane and SSH to server Foo, Bar and FooBar*. I've got the server config stored in .ssh/config and SSH key access sorted.

Is this possible? Using Powershell isn't an option thanks to overly restrictive IT policies and I'm not expecting much from the old CMD.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what exactly it is you're asking, but did you know you can send commands to the servers with single ssh commands? For instance, `ssh root@myserver "ls -lah"`. So you can put several of these `ssh` commands in your script to startup programs in these different servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you put this on the `"actions":` block in the windows terminal `settings.json`, it will add a keybinding that creates a tab with 3 ssh connections (will also create an entry on the command Pallet(ctrl+shift+p) called servers), you will have to type the commands in each one of them for now, but Windows terminal has a [feature](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/2634) coming where you will be able to "broadcast" the keystrokes to multiple panes.

```json
{
    "command":
        {
            "action":"wt",
            "commandline":"new-tab wsl ssh 'sv1';split-pane wsl ssh 'sv2';split-pane wsl ssh 'sv3'"
        },


    "keys":"alt+s",
    "name":"servers"
},
```

docs:
[actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/terminal/customize-settings/actions)
[commandline args](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/terminal/command-line-arguments)

Comment: I think for now this is as close as I'm going to get. Just means I have to remember a key binding